# scala program not terminating

Tags: scala, loops

so I'm rewriting all my code from project euler problems from Java into Scala so far successfully, but this one just gives me a never ending loop and eventually takes up all my memory... It's problem 7, here's the code

```
object Problem7 {
  def primes(current: Int, divisor: Int, count: Int, n: Int): Int = {
    if(divisor>current/2){
    if(count==n)current else primes(n+2, 2, count+1, n)
    }
    if(n%divisor==0) primes(n+1,2,count, n) else primes(n, divisor+1,count, n)
  }
  primes(2, 2, 1, 100)
}
```

I tried putting in a println statement after the first else statement to see if it ever got there, and it did. The program generates tons of primes, but for some reason it never thinks count is equal to current. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your last `if` should probably be an `else if`, otherwise your first conditional block serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first if statement has no else, which means it is only evaluated for side effects (and there are no side effects here) so that is likely a mistake, it should have an else.

The last if expression is always reached and always makes a recursive call to primes, so this will never terminate.

Probably you want the last if statement to be inside the else for the first if statement.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you know Java and are trying to learn scala. If that is so then try writing code in more functional way. 
Write lots of small functions to break up the work. Stop using so many if else statements which is going along the routes of imperative programming. Thats the whole point of functional programming. You should be able to easily reason with the program and not make mistakes with misplaced `if else` statements.

Here is a little more functional approach to get you started

```
def isFactor(num: Int, divisor: Int) = num % divisor == 0
def isPrime(num: Int) = num % 2 !=0 && ((3 until num by 2) forall(divisor => !isFactor(num, divisor)))
val primes: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(isPrime)
def findNPrime(n: Int) = primes take n last
println(findNPrime(10001))
```

This works under 3 seconds and has almost no optimization. With some optimizations, you can achieve better performance and the code will still be neater